# In Jekyll, wants to skip private posts to be rendered while listing all posts

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In my post file in `_posts` folder, I've written this on the top, yet it renders while I list down all the posts,

```
---- 
....   
status: private
....
----
```

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be the way in Wordpress to stop a post being displayed, Jekyll does not use the same key.

The correct way to suppress a post from being generated is to use:

```
---
published: false
---
```

(From the front-matter [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).)

Comment: This solution will not generate HTML. You're right. But in my case, I wanted to get HTML generated but just wanted to skip that post while listing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but I've finally got it working via following approach.

I added this in the top of post.

```
---
draft: true
---
```

I added these lines while iterating through all the blog-posts.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
     {% unless post.draft %}
      ///code
     {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You also could have moved the post file from _post to _draft. I had assumed there was a reason you did not want to use drafts.